# Aligning equations with {}

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, brackets, split

I'm trying to get the two parts of the equation aligned one below the other within the curly brackets. I tried to use split+equation, align, line break, etc, but I still can't get it to look right. Here's my working code (not the right output though)

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}


m_{cm,cc} = \{m_{cmp},(30^{\circ}+\gamma) < \omega t < (90^{\circ}+\gamma) \\       
              m_{cmn},(90^{\circ}+\gamma < \omega t<(150^{\circ}+\gamma)\}
               
\end{split}  
\end{equation}
```

I want it to look like this,
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `cases` environment for that, but I'm not 100% sure that what you're after, since you have a closing brace in your code (though not in the picture of how you want it to look).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
m_{cm,cc} = \begin{cases} m_{cmp},(30^{\circ}+\gamma) < \omega t < (90^{\circ}+\gamma) \\
              m_{cmn},(90^{\circ}+\gamma < \omega t<(150^{\circ}+\gamma) \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: cases environment]

If you do want a closing brace, then I'd use `\left\{` and `\right\}` wrapped around an aligned environment or similar, i.e.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
m_{cm,cc} = \left\{\begin{aligned} &m_{cmp},(30^{\circ}+\gamma) < \omega t < (90^{\circ}+\gamma) \\
              &m_{cmn},(90^{\circ}+\gamma < \omega t<(150^{\circ}+\gamma) \end{aligned} \right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: alignedlr]

Answer (score 1):

- Your code fragment  doesn't work due to empty lines in `split` environment.
- For writing of condition the `split` is not right chose,  better is `cases` with its syntax.
- For angles notation I suggest to use `siunitx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
m_{cm,cc} = \begin{cases} 
    m_{cmp},    
        & (\ang{30}+\gamma) < \omega t < (\ang{90}+\gamma) \\ % <---
    m_{cmn},
        & (\ang{90}+\gamma) < \omega t < (\ang{150}+\gamma)   % <---
            \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]